# There are no DynamoDB resources configured in your project currently while using Amplify Studio

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Using Amplify Studio I created a model, then "saved and deployed" successfully. Then I ran "amplify pull", but when I try to create a function "amplify function add" I get the error "There are no DynamoDB resources configured in your project currently"

Answer (score 2):

You can run `amplify import storage` to import the existing DDB tables into your local project.

Documentation: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/storage/import/